# Add Partition to table entrys

Tags: tables

I want to get a table like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gKZzEem.png]

How can I add the small square into the Table entry?

My current table looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt] {article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tabular}{c||cccc||cc}  
    &$W_1$&$W_2$&$W_3$&$W_4$\\  
    $S_0$&60&-&-&-&60\\  
    $S_1$&20&50&-&-&70\\  
    $S_2$&-&10&15&10&35\\  
    $S_3$&-&-&-&55&55\\  
    \hline  
    &80&60&15&65  
    \end{tabular}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As such, your image leaves a huge variety of possible ways to create it and users willing to help you have to start completely from scratch

Comment: Well, your table is a starting point, but let us wrap a complete document around it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative where matrix of nodes are used. The first and last row/column has different widths and heights. The positions of squared boxes, defined by `mysq` in the scope option, can be adjusted to suit one's need.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
  text depth=1.5ex,
  text height=4.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells
},
row 1/.style={text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex},
row 4/.style={text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex},
column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1em}},
column 5/.style={nodes={text width=1em}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% the matrix entries
\matrix (mat) [table]
{
  & 1  & 2 & 3 &  \\
1 & \textbf{\Large4}  & \textbf{\Large7} & \textbf{\Large9} &15\\
2 & \textbf{\Large 2} & \textbf{\Large 0} & \textbf{\Large 2}  & 10 \\
  & 8 & 11 & 6 &  \\
};
% the matrix rules
\foreach \y in {3,4}
{
  \draw (mat-1-\y.north west) -- (mat-4-\y.south west);
}
\foreach \y in {2,5}
{
  \draw[double] (mat-1-\y.north west) -- (mat-4-\y.south west);
}
\foreach \x in {1,3}
{
 \draw[double] (mat-\x-1.south west) -- (mat-\x-5.south east);
}
\foreach \x in {2}
{
  \draw (mat-\x-1.south west) -- (mat-\x-5.south east);
}
% the boxes
\begin{scope}[mysq/.style={draw}]
\draw  ([shift={(1em,-0.1em)}]mat-2-2.north west)node[mysq,anchor=north]{3};
\draw  ([shift={(1em,-0.1em)}]mat-2-3.north west)node[mysq,anchor=north]{2};
\draw  ([shift={(1em,-0.1em)}]mat-2-4.north west)node[mysq,anchor=north]{4};

\draw  ([shift={(1em,-0.1em)}]mat-3-2.north west)node[mysq,anchor=north]{3};
\draw  ([shift={(1em,-0.1em)}]mat-3-3.north west)node[mysq,anchor=north]{2};
\draw  ([shift={(1em,-0.1em)}]mat-3-4.north west)node[mysq,anchor=north]{1};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is based on adding a small `tikz matrix` in special cells (I didn't create exact table that you posted image to, instead, I used the same code you have provided)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt] {article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\newcommand{\nestedCell}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[matrix,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (A) {
            \node (b) at (0,0) {#1}; 
            \node[draw,inner sep=1, xshift=-0.7em, yshift=1ex,color=MidnightBlue] (c) at (b.north west) {\footnotesize#2}; \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c||ccc|c||cc}  
          & $W_1$ & $W_2$ & $W_3$ & $W_4$                   \\ \hline
    $S_0$ & 60    & -     & -     & \nestedCell{9}{4} & 60  \\ \hline
    $S_1$ & 20    & 50    & -     & \nestedCell{2}{1} & 70  \\ \hline
    $S_2$ & -     & 10    & 15    & 10                & 35  \\ \hline
    $S_3$ & -     & -     & -     & 55                & 55  \\ \hline
    \hline  
          & 80    & 60    & 15    & 65
\end{tabular}       
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add special cells by calling `\nestedCell{9}{4}` inside your target cell. A know issue, is when boxed number of one cell has more digits comparing to the others (e.g. `\nestedCell{9}{44}`). In this case, to have equal boxes, one has to use `minimum width=Xcm` to expand all of them equal width.